# Don't understand this switch and why the output is that

Tags: c

I don't understand why the output is only Warren. And what does switch(money,money*2) mean?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define L 10
void main(){
     auto money=10;
     switch(money,money*2){
        case L: printf("William");
               break;
        case L*2: printf("Warren");
               break;
        case L*3: printf("Carlos");
               break;
        case L*4: printf("Inqvar");
               break;
        default: printf("Lawrence");
     }
}
```

Comment: "I don't understand why the output is only Warren" suggests that you believe there *could* be more than one name for output; that's not possible with `break`s in each `case`.

Comment: Don't use `auto` in C code.  It is essentially pointless.  In C++11 or later, it is used wholly differently — your code might be OK as C++11 code, but then the language tag is all wrong.  See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch(money, money*2)` is as good as `switch(money*2)` in this case since the first expression `money` before the `,` doesn't do anything.

Comment: "...is as good as as..." should probably be ..."is equivalent to...".

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ, they have a habit of disappearing sometimes; someone felt guilty I suppose...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, yup, I agree. But this is rare. I've seen people voting on my posts and then reversing it, but I haven't seen someone reverse a downvote till now.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ, that seems contradictory; perhaps I am misunderstanding you. I often *hope* I'm able to reverse a down vote because many times it's there to affect change. I do agree, tho, that many don't maintain their votes well enough and as a result there are un-founded/corrected votes (those that persist regardless of edits).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, I agree that it is useful. I have myself reversed a few downvotes (and upvotes too), when I see that the post I have voted on has changed, and the DV or UV has become invalid. But many times after voting, I never come back to it. And yes, I meant to say that I have seen very few downvotes reversed; I ain't saying that it is a bad feature.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** First Expression 1 is evaluated, then Expression 2. But the value of expression 2 is returned. So this is basically equivalent to:

```
switch (money * 2)
```

**Long Answer:** This is a duplicate of [What does the comma operator , do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)